# Story haunting me: Man marooned on Mars, transformed into Martian

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Many years ago, while in my earliest 20's, I read a short story that has haunted me since. I am 70 now, and keep looking for this one story. My husband had a small collection of paperback books featuring short sci-fi stories. All I can remember of this story was a man marooned on (Mars?). He was without food or water, and was dying because of this. He wandered into a long deserted city? settlement? seeking shade as well as food and water. There was a terrible noise, a clanging noise invading his senses. He found a room that had a low trough-like place. He suspected food had come from a faucet device attached to the trough. In his final weakness, he lay down in the trough and passed out. Then he came to, hearing glorious music where the awful, strident clanging noise had once been, and the trough he lay in delivered food to his waiting and upturned snout.  So, in some way he was transformed by the planet, devices on the planet, something, to make him part of the society that used to be, and saved his life. Does ANYONE know the story I speak of?

Comment: "Enchanted Village" by A. E. van Vogt. It's been identified many times on this site. Hold on a minute and I'll give you a link.

Comment: [Click here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135844/short-story-about-a-man-stranded-on-a-strange-planet-slowly-changing-into-an-ali/135849#135849) to see the last time this question was asked and answered, and follow the links to find publication history, where you can find the story online, etc.

Comment: Oh thank you, could it be possible my search is ended?!

Comment: When you've made up your mind that this is the right story (I'm sure it is, you described it perfectly), kindly confirm by posting a comment, so we can close this question as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: YES!!! This is it. Thank you so much user14111. I can't believe after close to 50 years of this hiding in bits and pieces in my mind, it is now within reach. Thank you, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!  You have a remarkably accurate recollection after 50 years. Wish my memory was that good. Happy reading!

Comment: I want to thank you for all the help...and so FAST too! I found the book online and ordered it, can hardly wait for it to get here. Thanks ever so much. I believe this is the story that started my enjoyment of sci-fi.  jean

Comment: It's a great story and I don't blame you for wanting a hard copy, but I just want to make sure — You *did* notice that the story is available online for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Other_Worlds_v02n01_1950-07.Clarkcape1736/Other%20Worlds%20v02n01%20%281950-07.Clark%29%28cape1736%29#page/n5/mode/2up)?

Comment: I did, and there are some others I want to look for in the Archives, but this story I want to savor like a fine old wine. I read myself to sleep, and will be holding this as I re-visit the story. Reading at bedtime can be such a pleasure, and like I said, this is an old friend I will want to spend a proper amount of time with, getting reacquainted. I guess like a young person's first love, there can only be one first, and this was really my first in this genre.  I thank you so very much user14111, for your knowledge and willingness to help.