# I forgot the title: astronaut slowly turns into alien

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Does anyone know the story about an astronaut stranded on an alien planet who discovers an alien habitat or some sort, that slowly transforms him into  an alien being in order to survive its toxic atmosphere and to enable him to take in the alien food?

Comment: Book or film? What language? Where did you see / read it?

Comment: Read it in English literature class in college way back in the '80's

Comment: An edit suggester thinks that the book is _[Man Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_Plus)_ by Frederick Pohl,  although John already confirmed that it's _Enchanted Village_.

Answer (score 9):

This is likely van Vogt's *[Enchanted Village](https://jennre.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/the-enchanted-village-a-e-van-vogt-1950/)*.

> The lone survivor of a ship crashed on Mars encounters a living city that tries to please him but is unsuited to his needs.  The music is oppressive and clamorous, the shower delivers an acid bath.  With each drop of water it provides, a bit of the city disintegrates.  The man tries to commit suicide, reasoning that his fate is sealed and there is no need for the city to destroy itself.  During the night, it seems the city adjusts.  The man wakes up to a delicious meal, violin music, and a proper bed temperature.

Then

> He waddles off happily, unperturbed by his new snout and four-foot tail.

Comment: If it is, this is a duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37853/sf-story-about-human-adapting-to-alien-environment/37855#37855

Comment: Amazing. This is the story i've been looking for for such a  long time. Thanks so much Mr. Sean Duggan.

Comment: @John:
:) Can I trouble you to click on the green checkmark to accept?

Comment: where is it? I can't seem to find it

Comment: You should see it to the left of the answer, below the number and the arrows for voting.