# Short story pre-1978 astronaut? stranded in deserted city, saved by stone that gives up water

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to identify a story I read in a collection in the late 70s. My memory is sketchy but I think the story starts with two men, possibly astronauts. I think they are somehow separated (either one dies, or they split up). The main character comes upon the ruins of a city. He is dying due to lack of food/water and collapses on a marble-like (?) slab. A small pool of water emerges from the stone, enough to save him. And that's all I can remember.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Could it be the same short story described by [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/37853/40711) and its answer?

Comment: You beat me to it by 6 minutes. It is. Go for the answer.

Comment: Thank you both for your reply. I don't think it is Enchanted Village though. From memory, there was no house, and I think the water came from the stone itself, and it perhaps crumbled after it released the water. The implication being that the fabric of the ruins were trying to keep him alive. But it was a long time ago, so  my memory might be wildly inaccurate.

Comment: Well, Your description reminds me some of Stanislaw Lem's short stories (or, maybe, a longer one?) I read like 5 years ago. I couldn't recall the name, but assuming You read it in english, it may be better to find, what works were translated from polish to english (Stanislaw Lem was Polish).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanis%C5%82aw_Lem

Comment: @javajiven, I don't want to appear insistent :-) but an important point in "Enchanted village" is indeed that the ruins the astronaut stumbles upon are able to adapt to him and produce water only at the cost of partially destroying themselves (this is why afterwards a new strategy is adopted instead, and the astronaut is transformed into an alien).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mB0-KALpYmM Here is an audio book of The Enchanted Village by A.E. VanVogt. It even contains references to marble slabs.

Answer (score 3):

"I think the water came from the stone itself, and it perhaps crumbled after it released the water. The implication being that the fabric of the ruins were trying to keep him alive"

That is definitely from *Enchanted Village*.

> But there was another, less satisfying implication. If the village had to destroy a part of itself every time it gave him a drink, then clearly the supply was not unlimited - -  - - "not enough water. No matter how hard it tries". Realising he is dying, he climbs onto a central dais to let the village absorb his body and regain the water it has lost - and wakes up in the morning feeling fine. The village has transformed him into a Martian, and he strides off waving his four-foot tail.  .